# Reset form to specific value

Tags: javascript, html

I m trying write code that after reset set up rrpmax as 3000. It s ok with IE but not working in Firefox and Chrome.

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function formReset()
{
var fields = document.getElementsByTagName( "input" );
for ( i = 0; i < fields.length; i++ )
{
if ( fields[ i ].type == "checkbox" )
fields[ i ].checked = false;
}
document.getElementById( 'rrpmax' ).selectedIndex = 3;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="reset" onclick="formReset()"/>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<select id="rrpmax">
<option>1000</option>
<option>2000</option>
<option>3000</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just using the provided `reset` functionality of forms ?
(*without using any javascript*)

```
<form>
    <input type="reset" value="reset"/>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <select id="rrpmax">
        <option>1000</option>
        <option>2000</option>
        <option selected>3000</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/P6RR6/

Comment: You can't use attributes without values anymore. Proper way to use `selected` is: `<option selected="selected">3000</option>`. It's way more cross-browser ready

Comment: @avall, any reference for that ? because the html5 specs says otherwise.. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html

Comment: XHTML markup must be XML compatible which means every argument must have a value. Not everyone uses HTML5 yet.

Comment: @avail—and no one uses XHTML. I wouldn't have included the closing tags for the option elements either, and certainly not the short tag junk on the input elements.

Comment: @RobG "and no one uses XHTML". What? Maybe you don't use XHTML but if I code in a couple-months-old project I try to validate it properly with doctype. And yes. There are a lot of sites with XHTML doctype all the time. Are there either HTML5 or HTML 4.01 doctypes only in your opinion? :)

Comment: @avall—XHTML DOCTYPEs were popular (probablly because it makes the job easier for content management systems), but they are served as text/html. As a result, the browser ignores the DOCTYPE, effectively making them HTML 4.01 documents. If they are served as application/xml so that they are treated as XHTML, the web would be come dysfunctional for many users. The only benefit of a DOCTYPE in documents served as text/html is to trigger standards mode, that's it. Most are rapidly switching to `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`, probablly because it's simple and reflects reality - and triggers standards mode.

Comment: I guess you're right. Thanks for explanation :). And +1 from me. It looks like even validator won't treat XHTML documents correctly because of backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

this is a common error

1) first the index starts from zero the you should target  `index  2`

2) second for browsers compatibility and in case forgot the appropriate use in javascript
 use as
setting the name of select and the values

```
<select name="rrpmax" id="rrpmax">
<option value="1000">1000</option>
<option value="2000">2000</option>
<option value="3000">3000</option>
</select>
```

3) you can use

```
document.getElementById( 'rrpmax' ).value='3000';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give values to your options

```
<select id="rrpmax">
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="3000">3000</option>
</select>
```

And to edit the attr **value** of the select

```
document.getElementById('rrpmax').value = 3000;
```

Comment: That does not change the *value* attribute, it sets the DOM *value* property. Only in HTML5 are attributes and properties required to mirror each other's values (many browsers don't).

Answer (score 0):

You could add `selected` argument
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp